# How to embed noVNC in HTML pages

Tags: html, iframe, embed, vnc

NoVNC is a great web terminal to connect with the VNC server. We're trying to use it in our HTML pages. But the window of noVNC seems immutable.

We have tried iframe but it's not flexible.

So how can we embed noVNC in HTML pages?

Comment: I have been able to embed the page, but I am not able to modify the embedded window from outside the page.  To embed it, I simply start the websockify, which gives me a URL, then use that URL as the src for my embed, or the data for my object.  Currently I think Cross Origin is what is killing me, but that is for a different question.